# io.read() Doesn't let me input (Lua)

Tags: lua, io

So im making a exponent calculator and i added a feauture which on the case the number is too big to be calculated it will instead just tell you how many digits it has. Here is my code:

```
io.write("Number is to big, calculate only number of digits instead? (Y/N): ")
local ans = io.read()

if ans:lower() == "y" then
  --Irrelevant code (Doesnt get executed)
elseif ans:lower() == "n" then
  --Irrelevant code
else
  print("Error")
  os.exit()
end
```

It will always print "Error" and end the program, any help?

Specification: Its not that i doesnt matter what i type, its that i doesnt even let me type, the io.read() doesnt execute andit prints error (note: this doesn't open files or something)

Second Specification: It prints error before im even able to type something, i dont even get to press enter, and in my code before that snippet i call io.read various times and it works fine

Comment: Works fine for me if I enter `y`/`Y`/`n`/`N`. Errors for any other input, including no input (immediately pressing enter). Try printing `ans` (in hexadecimal) and check if there's some unexpected character included, e.g. a `\r`.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs Specification: Its not that i doesnt matter what i type, its that i doesnt even let me type, the io.read() doesnt execute and just does nothing (note this doesnt open files or something)

Comment: Might be an issue with how you execute/test your code. If I use `lua /path/to/script.lua` in my terminal with your code in `script.lua`, it works. If pressing enter doesn't actually get you past `io.read()`, then that's probably an issue with your terminal, or with how you run the script.

Comment: Your question mentioned that it always prints "Error", but now you're saying that it doesn't get past the `io.read()`? Bit contradictory.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs sorry if worded it incorrectly but it does get past io.read, what i meant its that the io.read does nothing

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs and i mean that it prints error before im even able to type something, i dont even get to press enter, and in my code before that snippet i call io.read various times and it works fine

Comment: Then something must cause `io.read()` to return early. Still sounds like an issue with the way you run the script, but can't tell.

Comment: Replace `io.read("*n")` with `io.read("*n", "*l")`